# extract specific fields from a file using a character delimiter

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have a 1gb file and would like to get the third and fifth fields.

The file is delimited by (,):

```
**input file:**
luis, jose, jesus atoche, mark, john
1,2,3,4,5
aa 1, bb 2, cc3, dd 4, ee5
```

out:

```
**output file:**
jesus atoche, john
3.5
  cc3, ee5
```

I understand that it can be done with the awk commands.

THANKS!

Comment: Take a look at awk.

Comment: You understand correctly. I assume you've googled awk, read a paragraph or 2 of the man page on it and tried something yourself so - what have you tried and where are you struggling?

Comment: If `,` is your field separator, why is there no white space before `jesus atoche` in your desired output? Why is there a `.` between `3` and `5`? Why are there two white spaces before `cc3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
awk -F',' '{ print $3 "," $5 }'
```

Where the -F specify your field delimiter.